# Como cadastrar pessoa jurídica e física em c# mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Como faço na Action Create do PessoasController para salvar os atributos de pessoa física e jurídica?

PessoasController:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "PessoaId,Telefone,Endereco,CEP,Cidade,Estado,Habilitado,Nome,CPF,DataNascimento,Profissao,EstadoCivil,Pontos,NomeFantasia,RazaoSocial,CNPJ,TelComercial,DataAbertura")] Pessoa pessoa)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.Pessoas.Add(pessoa);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(pessoa);         
}
```

Views/Pessoas/Create:

```
 @model PraticarEsportes.Models.ViewModel
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")

    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "Cadastro de Usuário";
    }

    <h2>Cadastro de Usuário</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">

            <hr />
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pessoa.Telefone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pessoa.Telefone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pessoa.Telefone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pessoa.Endereco, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pessoa.Endereco, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pessoa.Endereco, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pessoa.CEP, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pessoa.CEP, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pessoa.CEP, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pessoa.Cidade, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pessoa.Cidade, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pessoa.Cidade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pessoa.Estado, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pessoa.Estado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pessoa.Estado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Pessoa Física (Praticante): Nome -->
            <div class="Nome">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Praticante.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Praticante.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Praticante.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Pessoa Física (Praticante): CPF -->
            <div class="CPF">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Praticante.CPF, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Praticante.CPF, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Praticante.CPF, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Pessoa Física (Praticante): DataNascimento -->
            <div class="DataNascimento">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Praticante.DataNascimento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Praticante.DataNascimento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Praticante.DataNascimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Pessoa Física (Praticante): Profissao -->
            <div class="Profissao">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Praticante.Profissao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Praticante.Profissao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Praticante.Profissao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Pessoa Física (Praticante): EstadoCivil -->
            <div class="EstadoCivil">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Praticante.EstadoCivil, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Praticante.EstadoCivil, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Praticante.EstadoCivil, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Pessoa Física (Praticante): Pontos -->
            <div class="Pontos">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Praticante.Pontos, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Praticante.Pontos, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Praticante.Pontos, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Pessoa Jurídica (Estabelecimento): NomeFantasia -->
            <div class="NomeFantasia">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.NomeFantasia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.NomeFantasia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.NomeFantasia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Pessoa Jurídica (Estabelecimento): RazaoSocial -->
            <div class="RazaoSocial">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.RazaoSocial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.RazaoSocial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.RazaoSocial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Pessoa Jurídica (Estabelecimento): CNPJ -->
            <div class="CNPJ">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.CNPJ, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.CNPJ, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.CNPJ, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Pessoa Jurídica (Estabelecimento): TelComercial -->
            <div class="TelComercial">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.TelComercial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.TelComercial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.TelComercial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- Pessoa Jurídica (Estabelecimento): DataAbertura -->
            <div class="DataAbertura" id="DataAberturaId">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.DataAbertura, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                <div class="col-md-10">
                    @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.DataAbertura, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.DataAbertura, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>    

            <!-- Radio button para selecionar pessoa física ou jurídica -->
            <div>
                <input id="pessoaFisicaId" type="radio" name="tipoPessoa" value="pessoaFisica" onClick="habilitaCampo(this.id)"/>Pessoa Física
                <input id="pessoaJuridicaId" type="radio" name="tipoPessoa" value="pessoaJuridica" onClick="habilitaCampo(this.id)"/>Pessoa Jurídica
            </div>

            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    // Oculta os atributos da pessoa física
                    $(".Nome").hide();
                    $(".CPF").hide();
                    $(".DataNascimento").hide();
                    $(".Profissao").hide();
                    $(".EstadoCivil").hide();
                    $(".Pontos").hide();
                    // Oculta os atributos da pessoa jurídica
                    $(".NomeFantasia").hide();
                    $(".RazaoSocial").hide();
                    $(".CNPJ").hide();
                    $(".TelComercial").hide();
                    $(".DataAbertura").hide();


                    $("input[name=tipoPessoa]").on("click", function () {
                        // Se pessoa física estiver selecionado
                        if (pessoaFisicaId.checked) {
                            // Exibe os atributos da pessoa física
                            $(".Nome").show();
                            $(".CPF").show();
                            $(".DataNascimento").show();
                            $(".Profissao").show();
                            $(".EstadoCivil").show();
                            $(".Pontos").show();
                            // Oculta os atributos da pessoa jurídica
                            $(".NomeFantasia").hide();
                            $(".RazaoSocial").hide();
                            $(".CNPJ").hide();
                            $(".TelComercial").hide();
                            $(".DataAbertura").hide();
                        }

                        // Se pessoa jurídica estiver selecionado
                        else if (pessoaJuridicaId.checked) {
                            // Exibe os atributos da pessoa jurídica
                            $(".NomeFantasia").show();
                            $(".RazaoSocial").show();
                            $(".CNPJ").show();
                            $(".TelComercial").show();
                            $(".DataAbertura").show();
                            // Oculta os atributos da pessoa física
                            $(".Nome").hide();
                            $(".CPF").hide();
                            $(".DataNascimento").hide();
                            $(".Profissao").hide();
                            $(".EstadoCivil").hide();
                            $(".Pontos").hide();
                        }

                    });
                });
            </script>

        <!-- Botão Salvar -->
        <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                    <input type = "submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-default" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    }

    <!-- Botão voltar para lista -->
    <div>
        @*@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")*@
        <a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Pessoas")'>
            <img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/img/voltar.png")' class="botaoicone" title="Voltar" /> Lista de Usuários
        </a>
    </div>
   <!-- --> 


     @section scripts{
            <script>
                $(function () {
                    $('input, select, textarea').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).hasClass('input-validation-error'))
                        $(this).focus();
                    });
                });
            </script>
        }
```

Classe Pessoa:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PraticarEsportes.Models
{
    public class Pessoa
    {
        [Key]
        public int PessoaId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o telefone")]
        [DisplayName("Telefone")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string Telefone { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o endereço")]
        [DisplayName("Endereço")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O endereço deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
        public string Endereco { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o CEP")]
        [DisplayName("CEP")]
        [ValidaCEP]
        public string CEP { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a cidade")]
        [DisplayName("Cidade")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "A cidade deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
        public string Cidade { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o estado")]
        [DisplayName("Estado")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O estado deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
        public string Estado { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o email")]
        [DisplayName("Email")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "E-mail inválido")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O email deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a senha")]
        [DisplayName("Senha")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "A senha deve ter entre 3 e 50 caracteres.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Senha { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Habilitado")]
        public bool Habilitado { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Checkin> Checkins { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Classe Praticante:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using PraticarEsportes.Models;

namespace PraticarEsportes.Models
{
    public class Praticante : Pessoa
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o nome")]
        [DisplayName("Nome")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O nome deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o CPF")]
        [DisplayName("CPF")]
        [ValidaCPF]
        public string CPF { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Data de Nascimento")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "Formato de data inválido")]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt}")]
        public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a profissão")]
        [DisplayName("Profissão")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "A profissão deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
        public string Profissao { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o estado civil")]
        [DisplayName("Estado Civil")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O estado civil deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
        public string EstadoCivil { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Pontos")]
        public int Pontos { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Classe Estabelecimento:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace PraticarEsportes.Models
{
    public class Estabelecimento : Pessoa
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o nome fantasia")]
        [DisplayName("Nome Fantasia")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O nome fantasia deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
        public string NomeFantasia { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a razão social")]
        [DisplayName("Razão Social")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "A razão social deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
        public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o CNPJ")]
        [DisplayName("CNPJ")]
        [ValidaCNPJ]
        public string CNPJ { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o telefone comercial")]
        [DisplayName("Telefone Comercial")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string TelComercial { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Data de Abertura")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "Formato de data inválido")]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt}")]
        public DateTime DataAbertura { get; set; }

    }
}
```

Comment: Qual e sua dúvida? Dê mais contexto ao que está fazendo.

Comment: Na Action Create está salvando apenas os atributos da classe Pessoa, mas eu preciso que salve também os da classe Praticante e Estabelecimento que são herdadas da classe Pessoa

Comment: Atributos classe Pessoa: PessoaId,Telefone,Endereco,CEP,Cidade,Estado,Habilitado                                Atributos classe Praticante: Nome,CPF,DataNascimento,Profissao,EstadoCivil,Pontos                                  Atributos classe Estabelecimento: NomeFantasia,RazaoSocial,CNPJ,TelComercial,DataAbertura

Comment: Pode por favor atualizar sua pergunta com a definição dos Models? O código mesmo.

Comment: Coloquei os códigos das classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A questão é que você está usando a mesma tela para cadastrar tanto um `Praticante` quanto um `Estabelecimento`, o que pode deixar sua lógica bem complicada. O melhor seria ter duas telas: uma para cadastro de Praticantes, outra para cadastro de Estabelecimentos.

De qualquer forma, você pode deixar tudo na mesma tela, mas o correto seria gerar uma *ViewModel* com os dados das três classes: `Pessoa`, `Praticante` e `Estabelecimento`:

```
namespace PraticarEsportes.ViewModels
{
    public class PessoaViewModel
    {
        // Deixe PessoaId apenas se for fazer a edição da mesma forma.
        public int PessoaId { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o telefone")]
        [DisplayName("Telefone")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string Telefone { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o endereço")]
        [DisplayName("Endereço")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O endereço deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
        public string Endereco { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o CEP")]
        [DisplayName("CEP")]
        [ValidaCEP]
        public string CEP { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a cidade")]
        [DisplayName("Cidade")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "A cidade deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
        public string Cidade { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o estado")]
        [DisplayName("Estado")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O estado deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
        public string Estado { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o email")]
        [DisplayName("Email")]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [EmailAddress(ErrorMessage = "E-mail inválido")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O email deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a senha")]
        [DisplayName("Senha")]
        [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "A senha deve ter entre 3 e 50 caracteres.")]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Senha { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Habilitado")]
        public bool Habilitado { get; set; }

        /* Campos de Praticante */
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o nome")]
        [DisplayName("Nome")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O nome deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
        public string Nome { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o CPF")]
        [DisplayName("CPF")]
        [ValidaCPF]
        public string CPF { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Data de Nascimento")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "Formato de data inválido")]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt}")]
        public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a profissão")]
        [DisplayName("Profissão")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "A profissão deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
        public string Profissao { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o estado civil")]
        [DisplayName("Estado Civil")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O estado civil deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
        public string EstadoCivil { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Pontos")]
        public int Pontos { get; set; }

        /* Campos de Estabelecimento */
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o nome fantasia")]
        [DisplayName("Nome Fantasia")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "O nome fantasia deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
        public string NomeFantasia { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha a razão social")]
        [DisplayName("Razão Social")]
        [StringLength(255, MinimumLength = 3, ErrorMessage = "A razão social deve ter entre 3 e 255 caracteres.")]
        public string RazaoSocial { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o CNPJ")]
        [DisplayName("CNPJ")]
        [ValidaCNPJ]
        public string CNPJ { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Preencha o telefone comercial")]
        [DisplayName("Telefone Comercial")]
        [DataType(DataType.PhoneNumber)]
        public string TelComercial { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Data de Abertura")]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime, ErrorMessage = "Formato de data inválido")]
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt}")]
        public DateTime DataAbertura { get; set; }

        public TipoPessoa TipoPessoa { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Sua *View* `Create`, portanto, ficaria assim:

```
@model PraticarEsportes.ViewModels.PessoaViewModel
@* Não faça render de Scripts aqui. Use _Layout ou @section Scripts *@
@* Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery") *@

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Cadastro de Usuário";
}

<h2>Cadastro de Usuário</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">

        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pessoa.Telefone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pessoa.Telefone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pessoa.Telefone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pessoa.Endereco, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pessoa.Endereco, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pessoa.Endereco, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pessoa.CEP, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pessoa.CEP, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pessoa.CEP, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pessoa.Cidade, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pessoa.Cidade, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pessoa.Cidade, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Pessoa.Estado, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Pessoa.Estado, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Pessoa.Estado, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Pessoa Física (Praticante): Nome -->
        <div class="Nome">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Praticante.Nome, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Praticante.Nome, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Praticante.Nome, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Pessoa Física (Praticante): CPF -->
        <div class="CPF">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Praticante.CPF, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Praticante.CPF, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Praticante.CPF, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Pessoa Física (Praticante): DataNascimento -->
        <div class="DataNascimento">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Praticante.DataNascimento, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Praticante.DataNascimento, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Praticante.DataNascimento, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Pessoa Física (Praticante): Profissao -->
        <div class="Profissao">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Praticante.Profissao, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Praticante.Profissao, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Praticante.Profissao, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Pessoa Física (Praticante): EstadoCivil -->
        <div class="EstadoCivil">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Praticante.EstadoCivil, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Praticante.EstadoCivil, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Praticante.EstadoCivil, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Pessoa Física (Praticante): Pontos -->
        <div class="Pontos">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Praticante.Pontos, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Praticante.Pontos, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Praticante.Pontos, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Pessoa Jurídica (Estabelecimento): NomeFantasia -->
        <div class="NomeFantasia">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.NomeFantasia, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.NomeFantasia, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.NomeFantasia, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Pessoa Jurídica (Estabelecimento): RazaoSocial -->
        <div class="RazaoSocial">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.RazaoSocial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.RazaoSocial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.RazaoSocial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Pessoa Jurídica (Estabelecimento): CNPJ -->
        <div class="CNPJ">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.CNPJ, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.CNPJ, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.CNPJ, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Pessoa Jurídica (Estabelecimento): TelComercial -->
        <div class="TelComercial">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.TelComercial, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.TelComercial, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.TelComercial, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Pessoa Jurídica (Estabelecimento): DataAbertura -->
        <div class="DataAbertura" id="DataAberturaId">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.DataAbertura, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.DataAbertura, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Estabelecimento.DataAbertura, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>    

        <!-- Radio button para selecionar pessoa física ou jurídica -->
        <div>
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TipoPessoa, TipoPessoa.Fisica, new { onclick = "habilitaCampo('pessoaFisicaId')" }) Física
            </label>
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TipoPessoa, TipoPessoa.Juridica, new { onclick = "habilitaCampo('pessoaJuridicaId')" }) Jurídica
            </label>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                // Oculta os atributos da pessoa física
                $(".Nome").hide();
                $(".CPF").hide();
                $(".DataNascimento").hide();
                $(".Profissao").hide();
                $(".EstadoCivil").hide();
                $(".Pontos").hide();
                // Oculta os atributos da pessoa jurídica
                $(".NomeFantasia").hide();
                $(".RazaoSocial").hide();
                $(".CNPJ").hide();
                $(".TelComercial").hide();
                $(".DataAbertura").hide();


                $("input[name=tipoPessoa]").on("click", function () {
                    // Se pessoa física estiver selecionado
                    if (pessoaFisicaId.checked) {
                        // Exibe os atributos da pessoa física
                        $(".Nome").show();
                        $(".CPF").show();
                        $(".DataNascimento").show();
                        $(".Profissao").show();
                        $(".EstadoCivil").show();
                        $(".Pontos").show();
                        // Oculta os atributos da pessoa jurídica
                        $(".NomeFantasia").hide();
                        $(".RazaoSocial").hide();
                        $(".CNPJ").hide();
                        $(".TelComercial").hide();
                        $(".DataAbertura").hide();
                    }

                    // Se pessoa jurídica estiver selecionado
                    else if (pessoaJuridicaId.checked) {
                        // Exibe os atributos da pessoa jurídica
                        $(".NomeFantasia").show();
                        $(".RazaoSocial").show();
                        $(".CNPJ").show();
                        $(".TelComercial").show();
                        $(".DataAbertura").show();
                        // Oculta os atributos da pessoa física
                        $(".Nome").hide();
                        $(".CPF").hide();
                        $(".DataNascimento").hide();
                        $(".Profissao").hide();
                        $(".EstadoCivil").hide();
                        $(".Pontos").hide();
                    }

                });
            });
        </script>

    <!-- Botão Salvar -->
    <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type = "submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<!-- Botão voltar para lista -->
<div>
    @*@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")*@
    <a href='@Url.Action("Index", "Pessoas")'>
        <img src='@Url.Content("~/Content/img/voltar.png")' class="botaoicone" title="Voltar" /> Lista de Usuários
    </a>
</div>
```

Um detalhe aqui: repare que modifiquei o campo de escolha de Pessoa para suportar `Enums`:

```
        <!-- Radio button para selecionar pessoa física ou jurídica -->
        <div>
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TipoPessoa, TipoPessoa.Fisica, new { onclick = "habilitaCampo('pessoaFisicaId')" }) Física
            </label>
            <label>
                @Html.RadioButtonFor(model => model.TipoPessoa, TipoPessoa.Juridica, new { onclick = "habilitaCampo('pessoaJuridicaId')" }) Jurídica
            </label>
        </div>
```

`TipoPessoa`, portanto, precisa ser definido:

```
public enum TipoPessoa
{
    Fisica,
    Juridica
}
```

O `Controller` receberá, então, o *ViewModel*:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(PessoaViewModel pessoaViewModel)
{
    ...        
}
```

Repare que não preciso mais do `Bind`. `Bind` tem utilidade quando estamos usando um *Model*, não um *ViewModel*. Ele serve para evitar que algumas coisas sejam inseridas no banco indevidamente. Assim sendo, precisamos implementar o método para resolver o que estamos inserindo.

Para inserir os dados faltantes, a instância a ser inserida **precisa ser a entidade derivada de `Pessoa`**: Ou um `Praticante`, ou um `Estabelecimento`. `Pessoa` não é uma boa para inserir.

Assim, o método fica assim:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(PessoaViewModel pessoaViewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        if (pessoasViewModel.TipoPessoa == TipoPessoa.Fisica) 
        {
            var praticante = new Praticante
            {
                Telefone = pessoaViewModel.Telefone,
                Endereco = pessoaViewModel.Endereco,
                CEP = pessoaViewModel.CEP,
                Cidade = pessoaViewModel.Cidade,
                Estado = pessoaViewModel.Estado,
                Email = pessoaViewModel.Email,
                Senha = pessoaViewModel.Senha,
                Habilitado = pessoaViewModel.Habilitado,
                Nome = pessoaViewModel.Nome,
                CPF = pessoaViewModel.CPF,
                Profissao = pessoaViewModel.Profissao,
                EstadoCivil = pessoaViewModel.EstadoCivil,
                Pontos = pessoaViewModel.Pontos
            };

            db.Praticantes.Add(praticante);
        } else 
        { 
            var estabelecimento = new Estabelecimento 
            {
                Telefone = pessoaViewModel.Telefone,
                Endereco = pessoaViewModel.Endereco,
                CEP = pessoaViewModel.CEP,
                Cidade = pessoaViewModel.Cidade,
                Estado = pessoaViewModel.Estado,
                Email = pessoaViewModel.Email,
                Senha = pessoaViewModel.Senha,
                Habilitado = pessoaViewModel.Habilitado,
                NomeFantasia = pessoaViewModel.NomeFantasia,
                RazaoSocial = pessoaViewModel.RazaoSocial,
                CNPJ = pessoaViewModel.CNPJ,
                TelComercial = pessoaViewModel.TelComercial,
                DataAbertura = pessoaViewModel.DataAbertura
            };

            db.Estabelecimentos.Add(estabelecimento);
        }

        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    return View(pessoaViewModel);         
}
```

Um último detalhe: certifique-se de que `Praticantes` e `Estabelecimentos` são `DbSet<Praticante>` e `DbSet<Estabelecimento>` no seu contexto de dados.

Comment: Onde será definido o TipoPessoa? E mais uma dúvida, não poderia ter uma classe (ex: ViewModel) com public Pessoa Pessoa { get; set; }
        public Praticante Praticante { get; set; }
        public Estabelecimento Estabelecimento { get; set; } para pegar os campos das classes Pessoa, Praticante e Estabelecimento em vez de colocar todos os campos?

Comment: Sobre o `TipoPessoa`, normalmente defino no *namespace* em `MeuProjeto.Enums` (diretório Enums). Sobre dividir o *ViewModel*, não apenas é uma má prática como é incorreto. Uma `Pessoa`, pela sua modelagem, não pode ser `Praticante` e `Estabelecimento` ao mesmo tempo. Isto só faria sentido se sua modelagem fosse uma composição, e não uma herança, o que não é o caso, porque uma `Pessoa` não pode ser `Praticante` e `Estabalecimento` ao mesmo tempo.

Comment: Deu certo!!! Obrigada.

Comment: @GrazianeTavares [Veja aqui como usar o site](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour). Precisando de mais ajuda, é só falar.